# pagination issue using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using pagination with codeigniter but everytime i get only one result added when i change page.

Let's be clear, in `page 1` i have 15 different results, when i go to `page 2` i get the same results with additional new result at the end, when i go to `page 3` i get the same results as `page 2` but with additional one new result at the end ect...

**My code (Controller):**

```
$limit = (is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3)))?($this->uri->segment(3) - 1):0;

$offset = 15;

$query = "SELECT * FROM results ";
$query .= " WHERE user_id = '" . @$grow['user']->user_id . "' AND state = 1 ";
$query .= " ORDER BY created_date DESC ";
$grow['results_count'] = $this->db->query($query)->result();
$query .= " LIMIT " . $limit . "," . $offset;
$grow['results'] = $this->db->query($query)->result();

$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . "users/get";
$config['total_rows'] = count($grow['results_count']);
$config['per_page'] = 15;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><span>';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$grow['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$grow['site'] = $this;
$this->view('users/get', $grow);
```

**My view:**

```
<?php 
if (count($results) > 0) {
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        ?>
        show results here
        <?php 
    }
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
<?php } else { ?>

            No Result Found
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: please refer this link you will get better idea https://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/

Comment: i have an idea about how to make a pagination with codeigniter, but the problem i don't know where i made a false here !

Comment: your issue is in query your query is wrong.. in limit query offset should be first then limit

Comment: try with the link given by you to get more better idea try it out with that

Comment: Your issue as mentioned previously is in your query, for counting use this, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results WHERE user_id = '" . @$grow['user']->user_id . "' AND state = 1 "; ` and another query for the results. `$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);`

Comment: the query do not have a problem, i tried it and return good result ... problem solved commenting this line : `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;` but i want to use page number.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link you will get better idea..

https://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/

don't use custom query implement query like this

```
 $this->db->limit($limit);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get("contact_info");
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: the query do not have a problem, i tried it and return good result ... problem solved commenting this line : `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;` but i want to use page number.